# Border not going around entire LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to place a border around a `LinearLayout`, however it only appears on part of it. It only puts the border around the `TextView` seems to stop at an `<include .. />` tag. Is there something specific with includes or sub-layouts in general?

**Result** (hard to see because it's white on white)

[image]

The details are below. Any idea on how to get the border to extend around the entire `LinearLayout`?

**Layout code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/simple_border">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/dialog_action" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**drawable/simple_border.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: can you please put the layout of dialog_action.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your code by making new test project in my eclipse for your solution.

And I found that when I comment

```
<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/dialog_action" />
```

This code it's working fine...so there must be a problem is with `dialog_action.xml`

please check in that or post code here..

Comment: You're correct and I just figured it out. I didn't realize that the sub drawables to a View override things like shapes for borders. I simply had a white background in `dialog_action.xml` which once removed, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I also have check your code with my own dialog_action.xml it seems like below image.
[image]

So, it seems like everything is right in it place. Please put the code of dialog_action so we can help you more.

Feel free to comments.